# If I make an EC2 instance copy, the server settings like cron schedules are also copied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I need to make a test environment of a current running system.

In order to do this, I'm thinking of making a copy of the instance but, does the cron schedules will be copied as well?
Or do I need to set up all the server settings and cron jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to "make a copy of an instance" is to **create an Amazon Machine Images (AMI)**.

The AMI takes a copy of all disks attached to the instance.

Then, you can **launch a new instance from the AMI** and the new instance will have an exact copy of the disks from the original instance. This includes the operating system, applications, data, cron settings, etc because the disk was totally copied.

See: [Create an Amazon EBS-backed Linux AMI - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Computing (EC2) is only the CPU part of a computer; analogous to an "Intel i5"
Elastic Block Store (EBS) is only the Storage part of a computer; analogous to a "Hard disk"

The cron schedule is stored on the EBS, not the EC2.  If you want to make a "test environment" then you should probably copy the EBS, then attach that to an EC2.